Kafka producer is sending the message to the topic but consumer is not picking up topic on docker
I am using the docker compose to run my microservice application. I am using kafka message broker to communicate between two microservices.
The producer is producing the message to the topic (showing in the logs) but the consumer is not picking it up. Locally working fine


services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper-container
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka-container
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://config-server:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "baeldung:1:1"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network


  authentication-service:
    image: tejajagadeep/movie-app-authentication-service
    container_name: authentication-container
    build:
      context: authentication-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network
    links:
      - kafka
  userprofile-service:
    image: tejajagadeep/movie-app-userprofile-service
    container_name: userprofile-container
    build:
      context: userprofile-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
    ports:
      - "8092:8092"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network
    links:
      - kafka

I want the consumer to pick up the topic my producer is working fine but the consumer has some issue in kafka locally everything is working great

How are you verifying the producer actually sent the records? Can you run console consumer to see data?

When ever I hit the send is creates the topic but producer creates the topic meaning the topic is creating right and getting it right

I solved this I think there was some issue because I was giving the port using beans
